# Sorting off of a formatted date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table set up which reports history data. I have

```
SELECT ACTIONTYPE,
       BINNUM,
       DSID,
       LOCATIONNAME,
       LOCATIONTYPE,
       ORDNO,
       ORIGREC,
       convert(varchar(10),TIMEOFACTION, 101) + 
             right(convert(varchar(32),TIMEOFACTION,100),8) as TIMEOFACTION,
       TOTALLIFE 
FROM DLOCATIONHISTORY 
ORDER BY TIMEOFACTION DESC
```

I have edited the TIMEOFACTION column so that it displays the date-formatted field as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mmAM/PM`. However, the program that is referencing my query, is placing AM before PM because `A` comes before `P`. What is the best way to resolve my query to prevent this from happening? Is there a different ordering technique I could use?

My current reporting query shows:

```
**TIMEOFACTION**
12/13/2017 7:29AM
12/12/2017 10:07AM
12/12/2017 9:58AM
12/12/2017 1:51PM
12/12/2017 2:02PM
12/11/2017 11:01AM
```

When it should show:

```
**TIMEOFACTION**
12/13/2017 7:29AM
12/12/2017 2:02PM
12/12/2017 1:51PM
12/12/2017 10:07AM
12/12/2017 9:58AM
12/11/2017 11:01AM
```

Comment: could you use a different alias name and then sort by the original name of "time of action"

Comment: Sadly I can't. The fields that are displayed have to be a real column in the database and not an alias.

Comment: Really? Your presentation layer can't just take a column that's a real SQL `date` and format on its own side? The proper solution here is to keep the proper, orderable `date` on the data side and only manipulate its formatting on the presentation side. Anything else will be a kludge at best.

Comment: You can explicitly refer to the original attribute: `ORDER BY DLOCATIONHISTORY.TIMEOFACTION DESC`

Comment: When it displays a real SQL `date` it shows only the date & not the time. The only 2 things I can think of is either add a dummy column to the db for the formatted field, or convert the time to 24hr format as a last resort.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I was completely unaware that defining the table before the column would take the original attribute. Thank you for making me aware of this!!! It has resolved my issue. Can you please place your comment in a form of an answer so I can reward you for it?

Comment: @brad use a sql `datetime` to show the time portion.

Comment: @Tanner the field is a `datetime`, however the software strips the time for some odd reason. It looks as if @HoneyBadger resolved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: The order is correct in logic, 10 is greater than 2 so it is desc as it doesn't know the difference between AM/PM in that data type.

You need to look the 24hr time type and order that way.

What is the the type of TIMEOFACTION?

Answer (score 0):

LOL, just full reference column with table name or table alias:

```
SELECT ACTIONTYPE,
       BINNUM,
       DSID,
       LOCATIONNAME,
       LOCATIONTYPE,
       ORDNO,
       ORIGREC,
       convert(varchar(10),TIMEOFACTION, 101) + 
             right(convert(varchar(32),TIMEOFACTION,100),8) as TIMEOFACTION,
       TOTALLIFE 
FROM DLOCATIONHISTORY 
ORDER BY DLOCATIONHISTORY.TIMEOFACTION DESC --<-- here!
```

[Simplified sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cbd5/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( i int, a char(1) );
insert into t values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select -1*i as i, a
from t
order by t.i
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cbd5/3/0)**:

```
|  i | a |
|----|---|
| -1 | a |
| -2 | b |
| -3 | c |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select -1*i as i, a
from t
order by i
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cbd5/3/1)**:

```
|  i | a |
|----|---|
| -3 | c |
| -2 | b |
| -1 | a |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table with a column alias, then rename back to the original column name.  For example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(TIMEOFACTION datetime)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
 ('2017-12-13 07:29:00')
,('2017-12-12 10:07:00')
,('2017-12-12 09:58:00')
,('2017-12-12 13:51:00')
,('2017-12-12 14:02:00')
,('2017-12-11 11:01:00')

SELECT convert(varchar(10),dT.TIMEOFACTION2, 101) 
       + right(convert(varchar(32),TIMEOFACTION2,100),8) as TIMEOFACTION
  FROM (
        SELECT TIMEOFACTION AS TIMEOFACTION2
          FROM @table
       ) AS dT
ORDER BY TIMEOFACTION2 DESC
```

Produces:

```
TIMEOFACTION
12/13/2017  7:29AM
12/12/2017  2:02PM
12/12/2017  1:51PM
12/12/2017 10:07AM
12/12/2017  9:58AM
12/11/2017 11:01AM
```